# No se muestran imágenes en RecyclerView con Glide

Tags: android, recyclerview, glide

Estoy intentando mostrar imagenes en un reciclerView. No tengo problema para mostrarlas a través del ViewHolder directamente por lo que ni la vista ni la imagen dan problemas, pero si intento utilizar Glide no da error pero no muestra nada.

La llamada al recyclerViewAdapter la hago desde un fragment, y le paso el contexto para poder utilizarlo con Glide.

Este es el código

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);

    holder.mTipoView.setText(mValues.get(position).getTipo());
    String img=mValues.get(position).getImg();

   Glide.with(thisContext).asDrawable().load(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera)
           .into(holder.mImgView);

    /*
        Si pongo la imagen directamente si funciona

    holder.mImgView.setImageDrawable(thisContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera));
    */

    img="test.jpg";
    String imgPath="file:///android_asset/"+img;
    Glide.with(thisContext).asBitmap().load(Uri.parse(imgPath))
            .into(holder.mVImgView);


    holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (null != mListener) {
                // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
                // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
                mListener.onListFragmentInteraction(holder.mItem);

            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mValues.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public final View mView;
    public final TextView mTipoView;
    public final ImageView mImgView;
    public final ImageView mVImgView;

    public Receta mItem;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        mView = view;

        mImgView=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_receta_lista);
        mTipoView=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tipo);
        mVImgView=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_v);
    }
```

Comment: Bienvenido Mtoh, te sugiero leer [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: @Mthoh Tienes la imagen llamada test.jpg dentro del folder /assets? revisa en tu proyecto.

Comment: Si, la imagen está en el directorio. De hecho el mismo código utilizado en una actividad y accediendo directamente a la vista funciona correctamente. `.into(imgView)` Para probar también he intentado con un icono y tampoco funciona.

Comment: Agregué una respuesta, que versión de Glide defines dentro de tu build.gradle? eso puede ser la diferencia.

Comment: Prueba lo siguiente: remueve la variable final del tipo de los objetos de tu holder y cuando vayas a utiliar el context de Glide utiliza el contexto de tu padre del holder -> holder.mView.getContext(), esto evitara problemas de jerarquia mas adelante. Si no te funciona dejame saber. Intentas cargar una imagen desde Drawable?. Otra cosa, intenta cargar otra imagen (cualquiera) para probar si el diseño del layout esta correcto y te carga la imagen. Si no se muestra, entonces proporciona el codigo de tu layout y el codigo del LayoutManager que usas cuando creas el adaptador para tu RecyclerView.

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente te sugiero revises el nombre de la imagen y asegures la extensión es correcta.

Aunque veo que la version de Glide:

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
```

Soporta realizar esto:

```
Glide.with(thisContext).asBitmap().......
```

En este caso no es necesario usar `.asBitmap()`, ya que simplemente cargaras la imagen mediante su ruta (Uri) dentro del `ImageView`:

```
   String img="test.jpg";
    String imgPath="file:///android_asset/"+img;
    Glide.with(thisContext).load(Uri.parse(imgPath))
            .into(holder.mVImgView);
```

---

Algo importante es que usas un `RecyclerView` y veo que antes estas agregando una imagen, te sugiero limpiar previamente el contenido del `ImageView` de esta forma:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        holder.mVImgView.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
    } else {
        holder.mVImgView.setBackground(null);
    }

   String img="test.jpg";
    String imgPath="file:///android_asset/"+img;
    Glide.with(thisContext).load(Uri.parse(imgPath))
            .into(holder.mVImgView);
```

Comment: He añadido el código que sugieres, , la verdad es que ya no se por  donde buscar. El código   `String img= "test.jpg";
        String imgPath="file:///android_asset/"+img;
        Glide.with(this).asBitmap().load(Uri.parse(imgPath)).into(imgView);`      funciona en la actividad, el que no funciona está en Activity->Fragment->RecycledView.

Answer (score 1):

Al final he encontrado el problema. En el layout tenía definido:

```
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"....
```

Al sustituir

```
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Por un valor o por "wrap_content"  las imágenes se muestran sin problemas.

Comment: O sea si esta expandido el imageView inicialmente no se ve... pero si esta colapsado inicialmente se ve? Esto es algo raro que nunca había visto.